# Evaluation method that penalizes overshooting more than undershooting

Tags: forecasting, accuracy, model-evaluation

I want to evaluate a model that forecasts the amount of payments a company will receive from its customers on a certain day. I want to compare last years forecasts with last years actual payments by evaluating the model's accuracy.

The trick is I'd like to punish the model more for **overshooting** (*predicting over the actual*) than **undershooting** (*predicting less than the actual*).

Is there a standard way of going about this?

Answer (score 1):

The standard method of doing this (at least in machine learning) is defining a loss function which penalizes overshooting more than undershooting.

For example, if the actual payment is $x$ and the forecasted payment is $\hat{x}$, then standard regression minimizes

$E[(x-\hat{x})^2]$

where the loss function is the quadratic loss function, $(x-\hat{x})^2$.

To penalize overshooting more than undershooting, you can define the piecewise loss function

\begin{cases} 
L(x,\hat{x})=(x-\hat{x})^2 & x>\hat{x} \\
L(x,\hat{x})=c(x-\hat{x})^2 & x\leq \hat{x}, c>1
\end{cases}

and have your model/algorithm minimize that.